# How to prevent #+BEGIN_LaTeX from generating \begin{LaTeX} when exporting to .tex source?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am a beginner and have been using emacs for around a month. I'm still finding my way around. Sorry if this is a very basic question.

I'm trying to write a scientific document in org-mode and using org-ref for citations and references. I'm also using CDLaTeX mode for easier math input. To let org-ref find my equation labels, I have to enclose then in a #+BEGIN_LaTeX and #+END_LaTeX block. I have something like this

```
#+BEGIN_LaTeX
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:unitary-evo-state}
\ket{\psi(t)} = U(t) \ket{\psi(0)} \qq{and} \imath\hbar\ket*{\dot{\psi}} = H(t)\ket{\psi}
\end{equation}
#+END_LaTeX
```

When I export this to a LaTeX file, it generates the following LaTeX code

```
\begin{LaTeX}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:unitary-evo-state}
\ket{\psi(t)} = U(t) \ket{\psi(0)} \qq{and} \imath\hbar\ket*{\dot{\psi}} = H(t)\ket{\psi}
\end{equation}
\end{LaTeX}
```

The outer `\begin{LaTeX}` and `\end{LaTeX}` tags essentially insert a `\latex` before the equation.

Is there a workaround for this? I was using John Kitchin's org-ref [video](https://youtu.be/2t925KRBbFc?t=518) as a reference and this behavior does not happen there.

I'm using Doom emacs with TeX-Live on Ubuntu. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
#+begin_export latex
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:unitary-evo-state}
\ket{\psi(t)} = U(t) \ket{\psi(0)} \qq{and} \imath\hbar\ket*{\dot{\psi}} = H(t)\ket{\psi}
\end{equation}
#+end_export
```

If you use the new templating mechanism with `C-c C-,` you can select the "export latex" entry with `l`.

If this does not work with `org-ref` then I suspect that it has not been updated for recent Org mode: try updating and if all fails, contact John Kitchin about it.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This works. Is the other syntax deprecated or something?

Comment: Yes, see https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/etc/ORG-NEWS#L1851